# changing the color of a subgraph in igraph plot

Tags: r, igraph

I have the following code to plot the minimum spanning tree of a graph

```
## g is an igraph graph
mst = minimum.spanning.tree(g)
E(g)$color <- "SkyBlue2"

## how to I make mst a different color
E(g)[E(mst)]$color = "red"  ### <---- I WANT TO DO ESSENTIALLY THIS

plot(g,  edge.label=E(g)$weight)
```

That is, for a simple graph, I find the mst. I want to change the mst to red and plot the mst as part of the main graph. To do this, I want to select the edges of `g` that are also in `mst`. How do I do this?

---

UPDATE:

More generally, I have a graph `g0` which is the mst of `g`, which has `n` vertices. It was constructed as follows

```
## implementing the Dijkstra-Prim algorithm
v0 = sample(1:n, 1)
g0 = graph.empty(n=n, directed=FALSE)
weight.g0 = 0
while(length(setdiff(1:n, v0) > 0)) {
  ## chose the shortest edge in the cut set of g

  ## to find the cut, figure out the set of edges where vertex is
  ## in v0 and the other is not
  cutset = E(g)[ v0 %->% setdiff(1:n, v0)]

  ## find the lightest weight edge
  cutweights = E(g)$weight[cutset]
  lightest_edge_idx = which(cutweights == min(cutweights))[1]
  weight.g0 = weight.g0 + min(cutweights)

  ## get the vertices of the lightest weight edge, add to path
  lightest_edge = cutset[as.numeric(cutset)[lightest_edge_idx]]
  vertices = get.edges(g, as.numeric(lightest_edge))

  g0 <- add.edges(g0, vertices, weight=min(cutweights))


  ## now that we have the vertices, add the one that is not in the
  ## graph already
  for(vtx in vertices) {
    if(!(vtx %in% v0)) {
      v0 = c(vtx, v0)
    }
  }

}
```

I know I am probably not using a lot of useful features of igraph, but I do get `g0` to be a  mst at the end of this loop. Given this, I have

```
E(g0)
Edge sequence:

[1]   8 --  1
[2]   2 --  1
[3]   9 --  8
[4]   9 --  5
[5]   3 --  2
[6]   4 --  3
[7]   7 --  3
[8]  11 --  4
[9]   7 --  6
[10] 11 -- 10
> E(g)
Edge sequence:

[1]   2 --  1
[2]   5 --  1
[3]   8 --  1
[4]   3 --  2
[5]   5 --  2
[6]   6 --  2
[7]   4 --  3
[8]   6 --  3
[9]   7 --  3
[10]  7 --  4
[11] 11 --  4
[12]  6 --  5
[13]  8 --  5
[14]  9 --  5
[15]  7 --  6
[16]  9 --  6
[17] 10 --  6
[18] 10 --  7
[19] 11 --  7
[20]  9 --  8
[21] 10 --  9
[22] 11 -- 10
```

My question was, how do I assign an attribute to the edges in E(g) that are also in E(g0)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually quite easy because `minimum.spanning.tree()` keeps edge attributes. So you just need to assign an edge id attribute, and you'll see which edges to color red. It goes like this:

```
# Some test data, no edge weights, quite boring
g <- erdos.renyi.game(20,2/20)
g
# IGRAPH U--- 20 24 -- Erdos renyi (gnp) graph
# + attr: name (g/c), type (g/c), loops (g/l), p (g/n)

E(g)$id <- seq_len(ecount(g))
mst <- minimum.spanning.tree(g)
mst
# IGRAPH U--- 20 18 -- Erdos renyi (gnp) graph
# + attr: name (g/c), type (g/c), loops (g/l), p (g/n), id (e/n)
E(mst)$id
# [1]  1  2  3  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 16 18 19 20 22 23 24

E(g)$color <- "black"
E(g)$color[E(mst)$id] <- "red"
plot(g)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Gabor, that answered my question partially. My question also related to a graph that I made by hand. I will update my question but also accept your answer.

Comment: OK, I don't know why this is a partial answer, though. IMHO it does exactly what you wanted.

Comment: Ah, I should have clarified. I realized that I didn't fully ask the question I wanted :) Your answer was perfect.

Comment: What is the reason for reimplementing the spanning tree calculation? Anyway, all you need to do is assigning an edge id attribute to `g` and then when you add a particular edge to `g0`, you set the id attribute of the edge in `g0` as well. So in the end you'll know which edges in the original graph made it into the mst.

Comment: Thanks Gabor, that clears things up for me. There is no reason for me to reimplement the spanning tree other than a personal exercise in making sure I understand the algorithm. :)

Comment: What you said definitely answered my questions.