# Plot subnetwork over a network

Tags: r, igraph, gephi

I am using gephi for large network visualizations. I have a dataset that contains 16 000 nodes and 100 000 edges. I have plotted my network in gephi and igraph in r both.Though for large network visualization is a better option. I want to plot a sub-network which is the part of this full network and highlight only that sub-network over a large network. Is there any way to plot a network over a network in gephi or r.

Here is my r script

```
library(igraph)
g=barabasi.game(10,power=0.5)
plot(g)
g1=induced.subgraph(g,1:3)
```

Here g1 is a part of g.Then can I highlight my subgraph g1 over g by making only the portion of g1 to be highlighted.

Comment: The basic strategy would be to figure out which of the three major paradigms are used by the plot.igraph function and then use that appropriate facility for overlying graphical elements. Then you need to figure out what the coordinate systems might be. I'm not sure the second task will be easy. The plotting functions are base graphics but just using `par(new=TRUE)` would do what you asked but would not have the "1"-node of the overlay lined up with the "1"-node of the first pass.

Comment: I didn't get you @42- will you please provide a short example..??

Comment: `plot(g);par(new=TRUE); plot(g1)` ... I thought probably not what you wanted. Perhaps you just want to color the subgraph distinctly?

Comment: Perhaps: ``plot(g,  vertex.color=c(rep("red",3),rep("blue",7)) )``

Comment: @42- Yes i want to color the subgraph distinctly. But can we specify the sub-graph name instead of specifying integers..?? This exampe is just a small case in my example i am having subgraph from my original graph and i want to color that subgraph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok combination of the answer of 42- and the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646847/changing-the-color-of-a-subgraph-in-igraph-plot)

```
library(igraph)
g=barabasi.game(10,power=0.5)%>%
  set_vertex_attr("color", value = c(rep("red",10)))
g1=induced.subgraph(g,1:3)
V(g)$color[V(g1)] = "green"
plot(g)
write.graph(g,'barabasi.graphml', format=c('graphml')) # graphml can be opened by Gephi
```

The vertices of the induced subgraph are colored green

Answer (score 3):

This is really just a minor modification of the example in `?vertex_attr`

```
 g <- barabasi.game(10,power=0.5) %>%
  set_vertex_attr("color", value = c(rep("red",3),rep("blue",7))) %>%
  set_vertex_attr("label", value = letters[1:10])
vertex_attr(g, "label")
vertex_attr(g)
plot(g)
```

I'm not understanding the comments below. I thogut that I had done what was requested:

```
png(); plot(g); dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: But here i have specified the nodes in subgraph with 1st three bodes only.When i am doing this on large dataset then my subgraph will be having so many nodes and edges with in it. Then instead of specifying 3 and 7 in rep function can we specify graph and sub-graph name to color it over a network..??

Comment: This works fine but what is there any way if i want to specify sub-graph name and give it a color.

Comment: I have edited my question. g1 is my subgraph and i want to highlight g1 over my original network g

Comment: I don't know what "highlight g1 over my original network g" means. Describe in more detail what differences you need to see (or perhaps point to an accessible example of someone who has succeeded.

Comment: IMO he wants to plot the nodes corresponding to `g1` with a different color over the nodes of `g`

Comment: Yes I want to plot the nodes corresponding to g1 with a different color over the nodes of g

Comment: Perhaps you can be more specific about what's not successful about the answer?

Comment: IMO there's nothing wrongnwith your answer I upvoted actually. Only if I rrad through the lines the user wanted to color by the nodes produced by `induced.subgraph` and export to a format readable by Gephi, hence graphml